# How to pull objects using ActiveRecord into array based on their start_on date being greater than today's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a bunch of events and I want to pull them based on two columns. I need the 'publish' column to be set to "featured" and I need the start_on column to be greater than or equal to today's date.

Currently I have:

```
@featured_events = Event.where(publish: "Featured", ['start_on >= ?', Date.today]).all.sort_by &:start_on
```

I've tried a bunch of variations of this but no luck.

Thank you!

EDIT:: And the db I'm pulling from is mongo. Does mongo limit the number of arguments used on a 'where' clause?

Answer (score 1):

```
@featured_events = Event
  .where("publish = 'Featured' AND start_on >= ?", Date.today)
  .order(:start_on).all
```

or using 2 `where` calls:

```
@featured_events = Event
  .where(publish: 'Featured')
  .where("start_on >= ?", Date.today)
  .order(:start_on).all
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)' error when I try this.

Comment: @reknirt, dunno what to tell you, I just ran a _very_similar query (just different field names) in the console and it worked.

Comment: Does your where clause with the date in the second example have two args instead of 1 ["start_on >= ?", Date.today]

Comment: Yes, the where clause is this: .where("start_on >= ?", Date.today). So yeah, two arguments. How do I get it based on dates without two args?

Comment: try using Date.today.beginning_of_day

Comment: I should add that the db I'm pulling from is Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

1. "date(start_on) >= date(?)"
2. Time.zone.now instead of Date
3. combination of #1 and #2
4. Event.where(publish: "Featured").whwre(['start_on >= ?', Date.today])

Comment: When I use #4 I get "undefined method `each_pair' for ["start_on >= ?", Wed, 18 Dec 2013]:Array"

Comment: try to use without []